# I want to handle appengine_googleapis_com_request_log.protoPayload.line with BigQuery UDF

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I am exporting the Request Log of App Engine Standard to BigQuery.

Since the log output by Application is in protoPayload.line, we tried to process it in UDF.

However, due to a type mismatch error, the query could not be executed.
I'm going to make molds consistent, but how do I solve it?

```
Error: No matching signature for function JS:LINE_COUNT for argument types: ARRAY<STRUCT<time TIMESTAMP, severity STRING, logMessage STRING, ...>>. Supported signature: LINE_COUNT(ARRAY<STRUCT<time TIMESTAMP, severity STRING, logMessage STRING, ...>>) at [3:3]
```

Query:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION LINE_COUNT(lines ARRAY<STRUCT<time TIMESTAMP,
    severity STRING,
    logMessage STRING,
    sourceLocation STRUCT<file STRING,
    line FLOAT64,
    functionName STRING>>> )
RETURNS FLOAT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    count++;
}
return count;
""";
SELECT
LINE_COUNT(protoPayload.line)
FROM
`gaelog_from_bqstreaming.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_*`
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",
    DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),
    INTERVAL 1 DAY))
AND FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",
    CURRENT_DATE())
LIMIT
1000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? You don't need to specify the entire type:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION LINE_COUNT(
    lines_json STRING)
RETURNS FLOAT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
var lines = JSON.Parse(lines_json);
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    count++;
}
return count;
""";
SELECT
LINE_COUNT(TO_JSON_STRING(protoPayload.line))
FROM
`gaelog_from_bqstreaming.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_*`
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",
    DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),
    INTERVAL 1 DAY))
AND FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",
    CURRENT_DATE())
LIMIT
1000
```

Note that you don't need JavaScript for this kind of computation, though. You can express it with SQL directly, which will normally be cheaper since you won't need a higher billing tier:

```
SELECT
  ARRAY_LENGTH(protoPayload.line)
FROM
`gaelog_from_bqstreaming.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_*`
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",
    DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),
    INTERVAL 1 DAY))
AND FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",
    CURRENT_DATE())
LIMIT
1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's finally make the code that I made.
I wanted to search through ARRAY  and extract it and make it one STRUCT.

```
  #standardSQL
  CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION GetQueueStats( lines_json STRING)
  RETURNS STRUCT<email STRING, executed1Minute FLOAT64>
  LANGUAGE js AS """
  var lines = JSON.parse(lines_json);
  var result = {
    email : '',
    executed1Minute : 0
  };
  lines.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    var emailPrefix = 'userEmail=';
    var queueStats = 'TaskQueue.QueueStats:';
    if (element.logMessage.startsWith(emailPrefix)) {
      result.email = element.logMessage.substring(emailPrefix.length);
    } else if (element.logMessage.startsWith(queueStats)) {
      var vj = element.logMessage.substring(queueStats.length);
      var v = JSON.parse(vj);
      result.executed1Minute = v.Executed1Minute;
    }
  });

  return result;
""";
SELECT
  insertId,
  timestamp,
  GetQueueStats(TO_JSON_STRING(protoPayload.line)) AS queueStats
FROM
  `appengine.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_20171014`
ORDER BY
  timestamp DESC
LIMIT
  1000
```